# Как запустить каждую итерацию данного метода в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c#

```
public async Task Ping(int lowLim, int uppLim)
{
    string[] ipParts = GetCurrentIPAddress().Split('.');
    for (int i = lowLim; i <= uppLim; i++)
    {
        IterEvent.Invoke(i);
        PingReply answer = await AsincPing(
              string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", 
              ipParts[0], ipParts[1], ipParts[2], i.ToString()));
        string macAddress = await GetMACAddress(answer.Address);
        try
        {
            if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                PingEvent.Invoke(
                      answer.Address.ToString() + "|" + 
                      macAddress + "|" + answer.RoundtripTime + "|" +
                Dns.GetHostEntry(answer.Address.ToString()).HostName);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            PingEvent.Invoke(answer.Address.ToString() + "|" + 
                             macAddress + "|" + 
                             answer.RoundtripTime + "|" + ".....");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поверьте, вы не хотите запустить это в отдельных потоках. Если речь идёт о высокоуровневых вещах наподобие async/await, опускаться назад на уровень потоков — неправильно.

Что вы хотите, так это выполнить задания *параллельно*. А это делается просто.

```
public async Task Ping(int lowLim, int uppLim)
{
    string[] ipParts = GetCurrentIPAddress().Split('.');
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = lowLim; i <= uppLim; i++)
    {
        string ip = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                  ipParts[0], ipParts[1], ipParts[2], i.ToString());
        tasks.Add(PingOne(ip, i));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

async Task PingOne(string ip, int i)
{
    IterEvent.Invoke(i);
    PingReply answer = await AsincPing(ip);
    string macAddress = await GetMACAddress(answer.Address);
    try
    {
        if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            PingEvent.Invoke(answer.Address.ToString() +
                       "|" + macAddress + "|" + answer.RoundtripTime +
                       "|" + Dns.GetHostEntry(answer.Address.ToString()).HostName);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        PingEvent.Invoke(answer.Address.ToString() +
                       "|" + macAddress + "|" + answer.RoundtripTime + "|" + ".....");
    }
}
```

---

Кстати, не уверен в правильности исходного кода: вы точно не хотите внести сетевые вызовы под `try`?

Comment: Да параллельно, я извиняюсь за формулировку вопроса! Спасибо большое за ответ, все работает! И запросы под try занесу!

Comment: @БобровСаша: Пожалуйста! Вот и отлично, что всё работает.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Извиняюсь, еще один вопрос: этот код отлично работает в диапазоне одного байта(0...255), но в диапазоне двух, трех очень медленно! Да и главный поток тоже блокируется! Как можно решить эту проблему, этими же методами(Task, async, await) или использовать parallel.for или же что-нибудь другое?

Comment: @БобровСаша: А покажите код, который работает медленно. Попробуем разобраться.

Comment: Вообщем все тот же метод Ping(выше), только еще завернут в такой же цикл! Я решил не хитрить, поскольку других решений у меня пока нет!)

Comment: 'for (int k = lowLim; k <= uppLim; k++)
            {
                tasks.Clear();
                for (int i = lowLim; i <= uppLim; i++)
                {
                    string ip = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                              ipParts[0], ipParts[1], k.ToString(), i.ToString());
                    tasks.Add(PingOne(ip));
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                IterEvent.Invoke(percentage);
                percentage++;
            }'

Comment: @БобровСаша: Непонятно, где проблема. В том коде, который вы привели, всё хорошо. Висит, судя по всему, где-то ещё. Вы можете во время зависания остановить выполнение отладчиком и посмотреть, что у вас в стеке в этот момент. Иначе нам придётся гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, Вы правы, этот код не зависает, хоть и работает медленнее первой реализации! Вот этот уже зависает периодически(внизу):

Comment: 'for (int d = lowLim; d <= uppLim; d++)
            {
                for (int k = lowLim; k <= uppLim; k++)
                {
                    for (int i = lowLim; i <= uppLim; i++)
                    {
                        string ip = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                                  ipParts[0], d.ToString(), k.ToString(), i.ToString());
                        tasks.Add(PingOne(ip));
                    }
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    tasks.Clear();
                }'

Comment: @БобровСаша: Интересно, а зачем вам `tasks.Clear()`? У вас разве `tasks` не локальная переменная?

Comment: Да это я неправильно оставил, я ее вернул во внутренний цикл, но проблема не в этом!

Comment: @БобровСаша: Тогда дайте больше кода, в этом коде проблемы не видно.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Да, я как раз хотел предоставить Вам побольше кода, чтобы Вы могли понять проблему, но, как насчет открытия новой темы? В комментариях не удобно этим заниматься и забивать тему ими. В последнем комментарии оставлю ссылку на новую тему и тем, которые заинтересуются темой, подойдут постепенно. Да и система уже предлагает перевестись в формат чата!

Comment: @БобровСаша: Хорошо, давайте так и сделаем.

Comment: Итак, вот ссылка на новую тему: [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632186/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6]