# Как оптимизировать параллельный запуск задач асинхронных запросов в сети(продолжение темы из приведенной ссылки)?

Tags: c#, tpl, ping

[Продолжение темы из этой ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630056/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5/630062#630062)

```
    //************************отдельный класс***********************
    // Делегаты
    public delegate void DataGridViewUpdate(string result);
    public delegate void PingIteration(int iter);
    // События
    public event DataGridViewUpdate PingEvent;
    public event PingIteration IterEvent;
    //--------------------------------------------------
    [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SendARP(
    int destIp, 
    int srcIP, 
    byte[] macAddr, 
    ref uint physicalAddrLen);
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public async Task<string> GetMACAddress(IPAddress ip)
    {       
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
            uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;
            try
            {
                if (SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(ip.GetAddressBytes(), 0)
                            , 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) != 0)
                    throw new Exception("ARP faild!");                
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            string[] sMacAddress = new string[(int)macAddrLen];
            for (int i = 0; i < macAddrLen; i++)
            {
                sMacAddress[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");
            }
            return string.Join(":", sMacAddress).ToUpper();
        });
    }
    //случай - 1: вообще вылетает с ошибками
    public async Task Ping()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] ipParts = GetCurrentIPAddress().Split('.');
            for (int j = lowLim; j <= uppLim; j++)
            {
                for (int d = lowLim; d <= uppLim; d++)
                {
                    for (int k = lowLim; k <= uppLim; k++)
                    {
                        var tasks = new List<Task>();
                        for (int i = lowLim; i <= uppLim; i++)
                        {
                            string ip = string.Format(
                                "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                j.ToString(), d.ToString(),
                                k.ToString(), i.ToString());
                            tasks.Add(PingOne(ip));
                        }
                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    }
                    IterEvent.Invoke(percentage);
                    percentage++;
                }
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}  
    }
    async Task PingOne(string ip)
    {
        PingReply answer = null;
        string macAddress = ".....";
        try
        {
            answer = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip);
            if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                macAddress = await GetMACAddress(answer.Address);
                if (macAddress == "") macAddress = ".....";
                PingEvent.Invoke(answer.Address.ToString() +
                           "|" + macAddress + "|" + 
                           answer.RoundtripTime +
                           "|" + Dns.GetHostEntry(
                               answer.Address.ToString()).HostName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
    }
    //************************отдельный класс***********************
    //************************класс формы***********************
    // Обработчик события вывод информации
    public void PingInfoHandler(string result)
    {
        string[] resultParts = result.Split('|');
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
             resultParts[0], resultParts[1], 
             resultParts[2] + " мс", resultParts[3]);
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].HeaderCell.Value =
                                              dataGridView1.Rows.Count + "";

    }
    // Обработчик кол-ва запрошенных ip-адресов
    public void PingIterationNumber(int iter)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = iter;
    }
    //************************класс формы***********************
```

Comment: А какие ошибки у вас происходят? Это важно. И покажите ещё код класса `Ping`, может быть, конструктор или `SendPingAsync` делают что-то не то.

Comment: Или это системный класс? Тогда там, по идее, ошибок быть не должно...

Comment: О, а если убрать `Dns.GetHostEntry` временно для тестов? Оно может быть медленным.

Comment: Попробовал, но нет, не в этом причина блокировки! Здесь: answer = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip); Ping - это системный класс.

Comment: А какие ошибки происходят? Это важно.

Comment: Хорошо, а если ещё закомментировать временно все вызовы `PingEvent.Invoke` (их несколько)?

Comment: И `IterEvent.Invoke` тоже

Comment: Нет, он там один, но это не поможет! А как на счет применения BlockingCollection? Я пока с этими коллекциями не знаком особо, но такое чувство(исходя из того, что про них написано), что это то, что нужно!

Comment: Не-не, этот код должен работать. Это правильный подход в любом случае. А вы пробовали таки убрать вызов? Попробуйте. И ещё, какая ошибка выдаётся в случае 1?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Приношу свои извинения, Вы снова правы), это мои мелкие ошибочки (пропустил в многих местах обработку исключений)! На данный момент нет никаких вопросов, все разрешилось слава Богу! Спасибо еще раз Вам огромное! Чуть позже поправлю код темы и выложу для тех, кому понадобиться!

Comment: Вот и отлично! Пожалуйста, рад, что проблема решалась. Обращайтесь, задавайте вопросы ещё!